# Matcher & Pattern Android

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, format, matching

```
public String match(String cadena){
    String name = "";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(cadena);
    while (m.find()) {
        name = name + m.group(0);
    }
    return name;
}
```

Please help, I need enter string like this

> ej. :USD $ 2300.00

Result:

> 2300.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also try this pattern: `"\\d+\\.?\\d[0-2]"`

explanation:

`\\d+` - look for 1 or more digits between 0 and 9

`\\.?` - there can be a dot, but does not have to be (? = 0 or 1)

`\\d[0-2]` - after the dot can be up to 2 digits between 0 an 9

with this pattern you will return **2300.00** from **ej. :USD $ 2300.00**

Answer (score 0):

I just put this to my string:

```
v.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```